# How can I make the number of runs of an infinite algorithm fixed regardless of machine processing power?

Tags: python, algorithm

**Problem**

Let's say I want to build an algorithm that needs to send a message at a specific time and that also needs to run forever. How do I make this algorithm repeat the message a fixed number of times regardless of the performance capacity of the computer used?

**Example and further explanation**

This is an example that replicates the problem I had when I was working yesterday:

```
from datetime import datetime

i=0
while True:
    if (datetime.now().minute==21) & (datetime.now().second<=10):
        print(i)
    i+=1
```

If we call *n* the last element of the output of this algorithm, we can say that for *M* computers where the performance capacity of each one is given by

[image: equation1]

We will have *M* performances given by:

[image: equation2]

[image: eq3]

In the specific case of my machine n = 5,448,521

My question is: how could I write this code so that *n* would be invariant with the computer's performance, but that it would always be executed *from* the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're after something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

repeats=1000

done = False
while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    if now.minute == 21:
        if not done:
            for i in range(repeats):
                print(i)
            done = True
    else:
        done = False
```

(Though as a general point, you don't want a "busy" loop like this, and you probably don't want to reinvent the wheel with triggering timed events. You should use some library for that.)

Comment: where have you define `sent`?

Comment: Updated - the 'seconds' condition is actually superfluous.

Comment: I guess we're assuming that `repeats` is chosen so that each run takes a little less than 60 minutes for all computers on which this is to be used :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

i=0
triggered = False
while True:
    if (datetime.now().minute==21) & (datetime.now().second<=10):
        if not triggered:
            triggered = True
            print(i)
    else:
        triggered = False
    i+=1
```

Are you looking for something like this? You can modify `triggered` to be a counter instead of a `bool` if you need the event to happen a specific number of times instead of just once.

Comment: Better to call `datetime.now()` once for both comparisons; otherwise there's a race condition right at the end of the 21st minute, if the seconds tick over to zero between the two calls.